# Adding transparent characters into class-defined macros

Tags: pdftex, transparency, patching, transparent

This question is related to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439907/50886) regarding machine readability of a PDF generated using `moderncv`.

I'm trying add some hidden description within the PDF, so the information is not visible or printable on the PDF, but it's there on the copy-paste text extraction or through `pdftotext`. So far, the best way has been through transparency, using the `transparent` package. However, I'm getting errors when I try to add transparent characters within some macros.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\transparent ...n@ =\z@ \def \x {0}\else \edef \x 
                                                  {\strip@pt \dimen@ }\edef ...
```

followed by the line that calls the macro where I'm trying to put transparent chars.

I'm using `pdflatex`. Here's my MWE (non-working, because of the errors):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\section{First example}
Hello \texttransparent{0}{THIS IS FUNNY~}world

\section{Second example}
Hello \makebox[0pt]{\texttransparent{0}{THIS IS FUNNY~}}world

%the next line gives error
\section{Third \makebox[0pt]{\texttransparent{0}{ERROR~}}example}
This one gives error

%the next line gives error
\section{\texorpdfstring{Fourth \makebox[0pt]{\texttransparent{0}{ERROR~}}example}{Fourth example}}
Also error
\end{document}
```

Like I said at the beginning, my issue is with the `moderncv` macros and transparency. But I hope that understanding/fixing the errors in this MWE will help me address the ones on my document. Do I need to patch the `section` macro from article?. Or call the transparency in a different way

As always, thanks to the community for its help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\makebox` and `\texttransparent` are expanded when they are written to the `.toc` file to create the table of contents. You just have to `\protect` these macros when they are used in fragile contexts, like section headers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{hyperref}% You need to load hyperref to use \texorpdfstring

\begin{document}
\section{First example}
Hello \texttransparent{0}{THIS IS FUNNY~}world

\section{Second example}
Hello \makebox[0pt]{\texttransparent{0}{THIS IS FUNNY~}}world

%the next line gives error
\section{Third \protect\makebox[0pt]{\protect\texttransparent{0}{ERROR~}}example}
This one gives error

%the next line gives error
\section{\texorpdfstring{Fourth \protect\makebox[0pt]{\protect\texttransparent{0}{ERROR~}}example}{Fourth example}}
Also error
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!. How can I tell if this use of `protect` will work on my actual document with `moderncv` macros?

Comment: @phollox To *know*, for sure, only testing. But `\protect` is part of the LaTeX kernel and is designed for this kind situation, so I guess it will work if the use case is similar. If it doesn't, you can always post a question and link to this one.